# Should instant view be created for each page?

Tags: telegram, instant-view

We have a news web site and want to have telegram instant view for all news in our web site.

I have logged in at https://instantview.telegram.org/ and create a template for a news. by using its created link in this site the instant view button for this news is shown in telegram. but not work for other news. Should I create the link in https://instantview.telegram.org/ site for each news?

Answer (score 1):

You might have one of two problems.

1) According to the last abstract of [Instant View](https://instantview.telegram.org/):

> This means that, as a website owner, you can create a template for your page and publish `t.me/iv?url=...` links with the corresponding `rhash` to your Telegram channel — and your subscribers will be able to view your articles in the Instant View format right away.

Long story short: `rhash` generated for your news page could be applied to any page from your site. So make sure you have changed the `url` param in `t.me/iv?url=...&rhash=...` link while creating Instant View button.

2) Check the first step in every template in [Sample Templates Page](https://instantview.telegram.org/samples/). It describes which pages get Instant View and which don't. Maybe you've created your template for a single news page, not for all news pages at the same level.

E.g., the `?path: /.+` condition will provide Instant View for every page except the root page.